# Ошибка 233 при подключении к sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу подключится [image: введите сюда описание изображения]к sql server. В memneger studio дает ошибку: provider shared memory provider error 0 - С обоих концов канала отсутcвуют процессы. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-233-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16 См. напр. https://wiki.merionet.ru/servernye-resheniya/13/fiksiruem-problemu-sql-error-233/

Comment: @Akina, Делал так, не помогло. Я от не могу понять почему еще вчера все работало, а сегодня нет. Бывает что после перезапуска сервера, удается подключится на пару секунд и вскоре опять дает ошибку.

Comment: Если "вчера все работало, а сегодня нет", то однозначно за это время что-то изменилось. Осталось вспомнить, что именно, и либо откатить, либо адаптироваться. А поскольку возможных причин много, то только тебе разбираться, что именно произошло и как лечить.

Comment: может стоит перейти на TCP/IP ?

Comment: В общем даже не представляю что могло произойти между выключением и включением пк, но помогла переустановка sql server и managment studio...¯\_(ツ)_/¯